# What is problem with Sqlalchemy query? I'm getting back a ArgumentError

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to get all users from type DbUser
using sqlalchemy

```
   async def get_users(self, skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100):
        with Session(self.engine, future=True) as sess:
            return await sess.query(DbUser).offset(skip).limit(limit).all()
```

But I get the following error.

> sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Column expression or FROM clause expected, got <class 'apiacces.database.DbModel.DbRole'>.

Comment: `DbUser` is not a SQLAlchemy model class.